# Formatar JSON no EJS

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

ola pessoal estou com um problema utilizando nodejs e express, nunca utilizei essa linguagem e nao tenho muito conhecimento dela então tentarei ser o mais expecifico o possivel aqui.

1 possuo um webservice rest que me retorna pedidos de compra com varios itens mas resumindo seria algo mais ou menos assim

{
"nrSolicCompra":"94705",
"solicitante":"JSilva",
"itens":{"cd‌​Material":"259560",
         "‌​dsMaterial":"pregos cabeça chata",
         "qtMaterial":"1000"
        }
}

preciso pegar esse json e mostra no front end (que é em nodejs EJS)

atualmente tenho a seguinte estrutura.

uma pagina chamada index.js onde tenho o seguinte codigo que achei na net:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/teste', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('teste', { variavel: 'passou no teste', solicitacaoCompra: solicitacaoCompra })
});

var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/meuWebService/metodoRetorno',
    mothod: 'GET'
};

var solicitacaoCompra;

http.request(options, function(res) {
    var body = "";

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        solicitacaoCompra = JSON.parse(body);
    })
}).end();

module.exports = router;
```

na pagina teste.ejs 
consigo colocar este codigo para poder imprimir o json

```
<%- JSON.stringify(solicitacaoCompra) %>
```

e ele imprime em string o que eu preciso mas nao estou conseguindo guardar isso em uma variavel ou fazer uma formatacao em html para ficar em uma lista perfeita algo tipo

```
<table>
  <th> numero pedido</th>
  <th> solicitante</th>
</table>
```

a tabela inicial seria apenas isso e quando o usuario clicar em um botao chamado visualizar apareceria um modal com os items daquele pedido.

Comment: Podes colocar o JSON que o webservice  dá? o exemplo que colocaste em cima está mal formatado e não sei bem se é uma array ou um objeto.

Comment: claro é este {"nrSolicCompra":"94705","solicitante":"JSilva","itens":{"cdMaterial":"259560","dsMaterial":"pregos cabeça chata","qtMaterial":"1000"}}

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o que precisas é:

```
<table>
  <% for(var i = 0, colunas = Object.keys(solicitacaoCompra); i < colunas.length; i++) { %>
     <tr>
       <th><%= colunas[i] %></th>
     </tr>
  <% } %>
    <tr>
      <% for(var i = 0, colunas = Object.keys(solicitacaoCompra); i < colunas.length; i++) { %>
       <td><%= solicitacaoCompra[colunas[i]] %></td>
    <% } %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assim tens dois loops, um que itera os nomes das tabelas e outro os valores de cada propriedade desse objeto.

Comment: ola sergio muito obrigado pela ajuda, isto eu tentei mas ao inves de ele imprimir os dados no browser ele imprimi [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @user2913044 não tenho onde testar EJS, mas fazendo à mão para ter certeza, testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/yLzmxm94/

Comment: acho que deve ter alguma coisa errada na pagina index.js pq parece que a pagina teste.ejs nao reconhece json object somente quando eu converto pra string

Answer (score 0):

basicamente o problema que eu estava tendo era com o json gerado.

passei a utilizar o jackson framework e o problema foi resolvido sem alteracao no codigo.

o webservice é feito em java com maven, sendo assim para instalar o jackson eu somente tive que adicionar ao pom.xml o código. 

            org.codehaus.jackson
            jackson-jaxrs
            1.9.13